# Custom Keyboard Height and add custom view over custom keyboard in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, ios10, ios-keyboard-extension

I am going to make a custom keyboard for my app and also implement custom keyboard extension for enhance my application feature at input level,
 
So i want add **"custom view"** over my custom keyboard in my app. when i am typing some word at that time add custom view over custom keyboard like gBoard, so how can add custom view and increase size of keyboard more then 216.

Comment: I guess I did not get your question right. Is it so? Please look at answer and comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should put this height constraint into viewWillAppear

```
 CGFloat _expandedHeight = 500;  
 NSLayoutConstraint *_heightConstraint = 

 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self.view 
                                attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight 
                               relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                                  toItem: nil 
                               attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute 
                               multiplier: 0.0 
                                  constant: _expandedHeight];
[self.view addConstraint: _heightConstraint];
```

NOTE

In iOS 8.0, you can adjust a custom keyboard’s height any time after its primary view initially draws on screen.

Comment: i am implementing custom keyboard extension, i am not implementing in my app only. So can you please provide your input related to it.Please check my question i updated it.

Comment: I know , what I mean is that you need to implement viewWillAppear in your UIInputViewController of your custom keyboard , the self.view is actually your custom keyboard view

Comment: see this link with guidelines :

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html

Comment: you can save the constraint on property inside your UIInputViewController and use it to enlarge the view once they view is appeared on changing the constant of the constraint

Comment: of course your customview should be added with top,leading,bottm,trailing constraints to the main view before you can change it

Comment: This solution only for increase a custom keyboard height not for second question. if you know than please me also

Comment: you have to add your custom view to the main view (self.view) with constraints to top,leading,bottom and trailing , you have to do it programmatically with NSLayoutConstraint ,once its added the custom view will grow or shrink according to the main height constraint

Answer (score 0):

Adding a custom view over custom keyboard can be done in the same way you do it in your app. For increasing the height of custom keyboard more than 216, you need to add a height constraint to your `inputView` in `KeyboardViewController`. It can be done in the following way:

```
let constraintForHeight:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.inputView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 0, constant: height)
constraintForHeight.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh

self.inputView.addConstraint(constraintForHeight)
```

Feel free to suggest edits to make this better. Please let me know if there is any problem with implementation